# Voting pattern of 17-Sep-2013

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

I was looking at my reputation tab for 17-Sep-2013, it is showing quite some upvotes for some of my old posts that too continues...

```
 1  18840275 (15)
 2  18840618 (10)
 2  18840813 (10)
 2  18840813 (10)
 2  18628433 (10)
 2  18840813 (10)
 2  18826313 (10)
 1  18842048 (15)
 2  18842048 (10)
 2  18842520 (10)
 2  18842520 (10)
 2  18842520 (10)
 2   4616720 (10)
 2   4551178 (10)
 2  17140312 (10)
 2  17274503 (10)
 2  17403522 (10)
 2  18843640 (10)
 2  18844805 (10)
 2  18844857 (10)
 2  18844857 (10)
 2  18844857 [10]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18843738 [0]
 2  18844857 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844916 [0]
 2  18844857 [0]
 1  18844916 [15]
 2  18846002 [0]
 2  18846002 [0]
 2  18846499 [0]
 2  18846772 [0]
 2  16260576 [0]
 1  18846772 [15]
 2  18846772 [0]
 2   4616720 [0]
 2   4551178 [0]
 2   3896018 [0]
 2   1146651 [0]
 2   1249213 [0]
 2   4616694 [0]
 2   3846380 [0]
 2   1249205 [0]
 2  15610251 [0]
 2  18847560 [0]
 1  18844857 [15]
 1  18848439 [15]
 2  18846772 [0]
 2  18327257 [0]
 2  18849805 [0]
 2  18846499 [0]
 2  18850439 [0]
 2  18850439 [0]
 2  18850439 [0]
 2  18850496 [0]
 1  18850496 [15]
 2  18850439 [0]
 2  18846002 [0]
 1  18846002 [15]
 2  18851189 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  15400806 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 1  18850439 [15]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18851553 [0]
 1  18188102 [15]
 2  18851553 [0]
 1  18851553 [15]
 2  18851553 [0]
 2  18850496 [0]
 2  18850439 [0]
 1  18840813 [15]
 2  18854982 [0]
 2  18854982 [0]
 2  18854982 [0]
 1  18854982 [15]
 2  18854982 [0]
```

specially this block

```
 2   4616720 [0]
 2   4551178 [0]
 2   3896018 [0]
 2   1146651 [0]
 2   1249213 [0]
 2   4616694 [0]
 2   3846380 [0]
 2   1249205 [0]
```

is there something going on in those votes?

Comment: I think those indicate upvotes after you reached the 200 rep limit. After reaching 200, you dont get any rep from upvotes which is indicated by the `[0]`.

Comment: @AsheeshR yes those are.... my question was those are very old answers... how could so many of them get updated together

Comment: People might have come across them through Google searches, or browsing the site. Hard to say.

Comment: I, too, got a lot of votes on an old post around then. Pushed me into the rep cap, too. Alas I already have Mortarboard and am a long, *long* way from being Epic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see anything especially suspicious there. Someone might have gone on a little bit of a spree of "this guy is awesome", but those will be invalidated, if so. There isn't anything that makes it look like you or the other person(s) were trying to cheat, that I see.